# C64 development in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, c64

With the Vice C64 emulator I've got a tool called 'petcat', which converts BASIC (ascii text) to a .prg file for running in Vice. Previsouly I've been able to develop in TextMate and set up a key-press 'bundle' in there to make a shell call out to pet cat, passing in $FILENAME type variables, and this  creates the .prg file okay.

Is it possible to do this in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

sure, use an 'external build system' project. Then edit the MakeFile to do what you want.